# How can i use a video from google drive as my splash screen

Tags: android, video, splash-screen

At the moment im using a still image for my splash. but im revamping it at the moment and have made a splash using after effects. i have got some code that plays video as the splash but the file would be stored in app. i want to make it so that the video is stored on my google drive at this link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ydVvZW0PBnQ3IxcEdIYVJfWGs/view?usp=sharing

then played in the media player using the code below. it doesnt have to be google drive if you can think of another site ic ould use to make easier then thanks as well.

```
  String uriPath =    
  "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ydVvZW0PBnQ3IxcEdIYVJfWGs" ;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
    imgAnim.setVideoURI(uri);
    imgAnim.requestFocus();
    imgAnim.start();

 //  imgAnim.setVideoPath("android.resource://com.myapplication/" + R.drawable.vidio);
    int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 8000;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {  if (count <= 5) {

            finish();
            Intent Logina = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Homescreen.class);
            startActivity(Logina);

            finish();
        }
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);




}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335827/fullscreen-landscape-video-splash-screen-while-app-loads?rq=1

Comment: A splashscreen should load as fast as possible. If you load a video from an external source it takes a few seconds to buffer. That is why you should add the video as a resource. If you would want to change the video in your app, you could download a new video if your app is open. You could save the video in your apps internal storage.

Comment: use animation for this not video

Comment: the file is 25mb though and would weigh down my app. how could i make the file smaller but keep the quality.

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommend to use splash; Google used to advocate against splash screens, and even called it an [anti-pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEGWcMTxs3I&feature=youtu.be&t=1434).

In cold start sometime splash is good But If you want to play Video on SplashScreen it's not good Idea; Because streaming video take time and make user frustrated. If you don't have problem with this issue lot's of thread out there exist to play video [[example]](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html).

Comment: That video is from 2013. Since then, Google did a 180 and is recommending it : https://material.google.com/patterns/launch-screens.html#

Comment: Still doesn't change take a look https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/